# What's a better way to find if all the ids in table Y related to PK of table X are present in table Z in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a 3 tables X, Y, Z.

Entries in table Y has a column Y.x_id containing X.id as FK.

Entries in table Z has 2 columns Z.x_id, Z.y_id for X.id and Y.id.

X and Y has one-to-many mapping.

Y and Z has one-to-one mapping.

So X and Z also has one-to-many mapping.

What would be the best way to find if for a given X.id, all the related entries in Y are also present in table Z. If all the entries in Y related to X.id are also present in Z, I need to update a column in X against X.id.

Right now I'm writing 2 queries.

Inner join b/w Y & X:

```
select Y.id 
  from Y
  join X 
    on X.id = Y.x_id 
 where X.id= ?;
```

Inner joins b/w Y & X & Z:

```
select Y.id 
  from Y 
  join X 
    on X.id = Y.x_id
  join Z 
    on (Z.x_id = X.id AND Z.y_id = Y.id) 
 where X.id = ?;
```

And then matching count, values of these 2 queries (Java side).

Is there any better way to do this in mysql itself? I have very basic sql knowledge and am unable to find a good lead on this online.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry noted, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The [EXISTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-subquery.html) clause should do the trick.

```
SELECT Y.id
FROM Y, X
WHERE X.id = Y.x_id
AND X.id = ?
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Z
            WHERE Z.x_id = X.id
            AND Z.y_id = Y.id)
```

If you want to know if there are any rows in table Z that match those in X and Y, you can add a `count(*)` to the `SELECT` clause. This will return 1 row with the count of matching rows. Then, you can check if `row_count > 0` in your code.

```
SELECT count(*) row_count
FROM Y, X
WHERE X.id = Y.x_id
AND X.id = 2
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM Z
            WHERE Z.x_id = X.id
            AND Z.y_id = Y.id)
```

Comment: This is returning rows of data. Can I get something like a boolean value that says all the rows of Y exists in Z based on X's id? And thank you very much for your answer! :)